# Why URI path is returning false for file exist when I just created it?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

This is a follow up post to the problem I had yesterday. I have managed to use the DocumentFile class to create a child file of the image the user intends to  save on the directory user selected. I get the path property of that Uri object stored in the newly created document file and I use it to check if the file exists. Unfortunately it returns false and I cannot seem to understand why.

```
if(documentFile! = null && documentFile.Exists() && documentFile.IsDirectory){
  //create a new child file in this directory
  DocumentFile docFile = documentFile.CreateFile("image/png", filename);
 //get the path associated with the uri of the newly created file
 fullPath = docFile.Uri.Path;
 //check if the file exists, I can see in the testing device the file is created
 Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(fullPath);
 if(file.Exists()){
   Toast.MakeText(this, "file exists", ToastLength.Short).Show();
  }else{
    Toast.MakeText(this,"file does not exist", ToastLength.Short).Show();
  }
}
```

I really need the File.Exists to return true for copying bytes from an image to the blank file. I do not understand why am able to see the newly created image file in the testing device internal storage but the block returns false.

Comment: why are you mixing Android `DocumentFile` with .NET `System.IO.File`?   From the docs, "That is, documents don't have a strong notion of path" which makes me think they are not guaranteed to behave as expected when using traditional file IO

Comment: @Jason, there has been a misunderstanding the File class I am using belongs to the Java.IO name space

Comment: You just should not use a File class.